# Linux Mint Localhost browser Not Accepting Changes

Tags: php, linux, laravel, linux-mint

As specified by title, my linux mint does not execute newer version of page in localhost with php 7.0 and mariadb apache2, (using laravel).

i bet this problem is weirdest problem ever i encounter, because no matter what am writing in page its keep showing previous version of it.

Okay let me explain, like i created a file named **anything.blade.php**, and put contents like simple html with blade template eg:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<a href="#Dashboard">Dashboard</a>
@endsection
```

And now assume i need to change anchor url for some reason, it wont take effect any how ! :( no matter what am doing with file, after deleting entire markup from file, it still showing previous version of file, with old link.

**And no problem with windows OS, besides its happening some times in linux via random files :( and localhost:90 is always running as laravel root once started by *"php -S localhost:90 -t public"***

Again am specifying it as a very complex and fuzzy problem, googled several time with little or no luck :'( StackOverFlow is a Final Destination.

Comment: Look into Laravel caching.  Seems to be an issue with that in your case

Comment: @JimL Probably a cache problem, but not on Laravel's side, since OP says it works on Windows.

Comment: Try to clear your cache ( php artisan view:clear ) and if it works, there is something wrong with last file updated in your linux.

Comment: it worked ! thanks !